# base64 decryption with unknown encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, encryption

How to decrypt a base64 string with unknown encryption algorithm?

There is a base64 string:

LcIagpWwd+Dg3mmJH/jFkQ==

This isn't normal base64 because doesn't decode
I think this was a text that encoded to base64 then encrypted with an algorithm

I don't know the encryption algorithm. How to decrypt it?

Comment: your encryption tag doesn't match the question. it should be encoding

Comment: You can't.  If you don't know the algorithm, then it is possibly encrypted with a One Time Pad, and hence is undecryptable.  Whatever result you get from decrypting cannot be confirmed as correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, since ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but you can guess yourself: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a normal Base64 encoding of binary data, it decodes to 16 bytes (displayed as hex):

> 2DC21A8295B077E0E0DE69891FF8C591

That could be encrypted data, the length is typical of block encryption. Base64 is generally used to encode binary data in a text format and encryption produced what appears as random bytes. If this is true it is backwards from the question, it would be something encrypted and then that Base64 encoded.

If this is encrypted the real issue it that the encryption key is needed to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 doesn't include encryption. You can convert it to byte array. Maybe byte array has encryption but you need a lot of sample for determining there is encryption or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean encryption is the variation of base64 encoding? as we should use same encoding method to decode the base64 string. It is not encrypted, so you were wrong saying it encryption and decryption.
you can refer to this link to make a self-built base 64 decoder [wikipedia base 64 implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history)

But most programming language has built in base 64 decoding and encoding function doesn't it?
just use those built in function instead of inventing the same wheel over again.

Comment: Yes I know. But this isn't normal base64. This code encrypted